# Fire action when onchange and onload events triggered for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to do this in pure js. So far I have something along the lines of:

```
document.getElementById('mySelectBox').onchange = function(e) {
  // hide some element if this.value == 'hide'.....
}
```

Is there a clean way to trigger the hide code in the above block when my dropdown loads/gets its initial value as well, or possibly bind the above action to `onload` and `onchange` events at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el =  document.getElementById('mySelectBox');

['load', 'change'].forEach(event => el.addEventListener(event, function(e){
         /* your code here */
}))
```